# How to find which shared library is loaded by a process on OSX?

Tags: snow-leopard, library, dtrace, dynamic-library

I am trying to compile and use a shared C library as a python module and I am observing that depending on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` my code works or it crashes with a cryptic error message.

```
Jul 24 02:44:44 master 
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib  python -c 'import opengm' 
OKAY

Jul 24 02:45:41 master 
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= python -c 'import opengm' 
python(86214,0x7fff70ccdcc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff70177500: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

I have tried to manually inspect which libraries are common between `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` and `/opt/local/lib` but I have not been able to find the cause of the crash. One way to figure out the cause of the problem will be to figure out which `dylib` files do the two processes use? I was not able to figure this using `opensnoop` or `dtruss` but maybe I was using those tools wrong.

How can I figure out the cause of this crash?

**DISCLAIMER:** I posted this same question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549523) 2 days ago, where it did not receive any replies and only 8 views.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please don't crosspost. In the future, if you want to move questions to another site, just flag it for mod attention and ask the moderators to migrate it to the other site.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the cross post.

Comment: No worries, we all live and learn :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES` in the environment to have `dyld` print every dynamic library that it loads into the process:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES /usr/bin/true 
dyld: loaded: /usr/bin/true
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
[ ... snip ... ]
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
$
```

Comment: Note that with the introduction of SIP, all environment variables matching DYLD_* will be stripped before executing a restricted binary, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40810069/2173773) answer. So using `/usr/bin/true` as in this example, will actually produce no output since it is restricted and then `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES` will be removed

Answer (score 3):

One program that can show which `dylib` files have been used to execute a program is `otool`.

```
otool -L /path/to/program
```

Comment: otool shows `@rpath/libz.1.dylib` and `@rpath/libpython2.7.dylib`. The rest of libraries have complete paths. This probably means that if I somehow set the rpath correctly in the compiled dylib then everything will be fine. Thanks for your answer.